# Heap not generated when using -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, tomcat, heap-memory, heap-dump

I'm having a problem where a `Java webapp` running in `Tomcat` is throwing a lot of `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` errors, but no heap is being generated.

I have the following flags in `CATALINA_OPTS` enabled via `setenv.sh`

`-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/path/to/`

This has worked before, but for some reason it's just not now.

Usually I would see `Dumping heap to /path/to/heap/dir/` in `catalina.out`, but not this time.

The VM options are most definitely enabled as seen by the output of `ps`

The heap directory has sufficient space and write permissions (I think this kind of IO exception is actually logged)

The OutOfMemory is being caused due to far to heavy `XSL Transformation` happening within a `JSP` via taglibs.

Stack looks like this following:

```
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:861)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:794)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.portlets.item_005fsearch.result.view_jsp._jspService(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:229)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewRendererServlet.renderView(ViewRendererServlet.java:114)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewRendererServlet.processRequest(ViewRendererServlet.java:86)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewRendererServlet.doGet(ViewRendererServlet.java:66)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)
    at org.exoplatform.services.portletcontainer.plugins.pc.portletAPIImp.PortletRequestDispatcherImp.include(PortletRequestDispatcherImp.java:149)
    ... 88 more

Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TemplatesImpl.getTransletInstance(TemplatesImpl.java:353)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TemplatesImpl.newTransformer(TemplatesImpl.java:382)....
```

I'm trying to understand, under what circumstances would an OutOfMemoryError not trigger the heap dump.

Thanks in advance.

Will

Comment: It looks like Tomcat is catching and rethrowing the error as a cause exception. I'm not sure how to correct it though. Heap dumps are only created when the error is uncaught and populates all the way to the root of the stack trace without being handled.

Comment: Brian is right, I know tomcat 7 have Leak protection. You might want to disable them so that it generates the dump for you.